# What tricks can be used to prevent debugging?

Tags: reverse-engineering, shellcode, debugging

What tricks can be used to prevent or hinder debugging?

Examples:

- `IsDebuggerPresent` API on Windows
- Exception handlers used for program flow.
- `GetTickCount` / `rdtsc` checks.

Are there any good resources on this kind of thing?

Comment: @AndrewSmith Care to substantiate your claims about banks using that technique? I've never heard of it.

Comment: @Andrew - why write unsubstantiated and untrue nonsense? What makes you think any bank wants to obfuscate code and make their own debugging more difficult?

Comment: Better one silly idea then none!

Comment: @AndrewSmith I cannot describe how fundamentally opposed I am to that sentiment.

Comment: I also cannot describe how well I do understand it too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could begin looking at Symantec: http://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/windows-anti-debug-reference

And there is a question in [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573115/what-is-your-favourite-anti-debugging-trick) about anti-debugging tricks.

Comment: Figured someone would drop the Symantec paper on here at some point :)

Comment: :) think it's the only one I ever read about it...